# Extract a letter from a list of numbers

Tags: python

I have this problem:

```
number = 'a1234'
alphabet= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

I need to convert the number to:

```
number = 1234
```

But I haven't every time got 'a' in number, I could have any random letter in alphabet array

Can I check this in a faster way than this, if it is possible?

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    for a in pid :
        if a in alphabet:
            pid = pid.replace(a, '')
            pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression.

```
import pdb, re

pdb.set_trace()

pid = 'a1234'
pid = re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', '', pid) #remove all letters from pid
print(pid) #1234
```